# What do the __CC_ARM, __ICCARM__, __GNUC__ and __TASKING__ macros mean?

Tags: c, data-structures, embedded, microcontroller

I am working on STM32l151rct6a by stm, I have stumbled upon these MACRO definitions

```
__CC_ARM, __ICCARM__, __GNUC__, __TASKING__
```

Does anyone know what they mean?

Answer (score 15):

These are different compilers for ARM processors, probably these macros are used to hide compiler-dependent stuff in code that's compilable by several compilers.

- `__ICCARM__` --> [IAR](https://wwwfiles.iar.com/arm/webic/doc/ewarm_developmentguide.enu.pdf) (there will also be a macro `__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__` that is set to the compiler platform version
- `__IMAGECRAFT__` --> [Imagecraft C](https://www.imagecraft.com/) (also see Clifford's comments below - there's also a macro `__ICC_VERSION__`, see the [pdf documentation](https://www.imagecraft.com/help/iccv8cortex/ICCCORTEX.pdf))
- `TASKING` --> [Tasking](https://www.tasking.com/products/arm/)
- `__CC_ARM` --> [ARM's (RealView) compiler](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0282b/Babbacdb.html) (link broken)
- `__GNUC__`  --> [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 2):

They are macros for identifying the compiler being used to build the code.

A list of such macros, and others for identifying architecture and OS etc. can be found at http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/.  It does not however comprehensively cover many compilers from smaller embedded systems vendors (Tasking and Imagecraft for example).

Answer (score 1):

These are compiler specific MACROS and defined in compiler code.For example __ICC is for IAR and __GNU is for GNU compilers.There are some code given in BSP part for STM platform which have dependency on compilers.

Comment: According to http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/ IAR is identified by  __IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__.  Another answer here suggests Imagecraft C for _ICC which sounds plausible.

Comment: @Clifford Line `#elif defined ( __ICCARM__ ) /* IAR Ewarm 5.41+ */` on [This Link](http://asf.atmel.com/docs/latest/sam.drivers.usart.usart_synchronous_example.sam3u_ek/html/compiler_8h_source.html) and [This link](http://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/usb-library-iccarm-definition) Talks about IAR only.

Comment: @Dayalrai: Indeed - there is no standard, IAR and Imagecraft may have both used this, the other answer may be incorrect and the Sourceforge wiki may be incomplete or contain errors.  Always use such macros with caution.

Comment: The other answer was incorrect - Imagecraft use `__IMAGECRAFT__` [says the manual](https://www.imagecraft.com/help/iccv8cortex/ICCCORTEX.pdf). They do have another `__ICC_VERSION` which may cause confusion.

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for more clarity and reliable links on this thread.

Comment: @dayalrai talking about links, how about a link to that BSP code you're referring to?

Comment: @fvu i am not sure what are you asking for.But may be [this link](https://github.com/kapusy/stm32/blob/master/stm32server/cmsis/core_cm3.c) will throw some light.

Comment: @dayalrai thanks, great - that source confirms that `__CC_ARM` is actually RealView.