# What is this #ifdef __GNUC__ about?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, predefined-macro

I've found these lines in [the `libmagic` code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/). What do they mean?

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
__attribute__((unused))
#endif
```

**What does `__GNUC__` mean?**
It seems to check [whether GCC is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572519/what-means-cc-arm-iccarm-gnuc-tasking).

**What is `__attribute__((unused))`?**
There's a code snippet here but no explanation: [How do I best silence a warning about unused variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486904/how-do-i-best-silence-a-warning-about-unused-variables)

**What is the difference between `__GNUC__` and `_MSC_VER`?**
There's some explanation on `_MSC_VER`, but what is it all about?
[How to Detect if I'm Compiling Code with a particular Visual Studio version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70013/how-to-detect-if-im-compiling-code-with-visual-studio-2008)

Finally the question:
**How can I do the same `#ifdef` to check which compiler is compiling my code?**

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Comment: This is the most bizarre question ever in the way it's formulated, but I'm coming from a past world where people used to first have a look at documentation, in a time where documentation was a thing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's common in compilers to define macros to determine what compiler they are, what version is that, ... a portable C++ code can use them to find out that it can use a specific feature or not.

> What does `__GNUC__` mean?

It indicates that I'm a GNU compiler and you can use GNU extensions. [[1]](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html)

> What is `__attribute__((unused))`?

This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce an unused-variable-warning for this variable. [[2]](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

> What is the difference between `__GNUC__` and `_MSC_VER`?

They're two unrelated macros. First one says I'm am a GNU compiler and second one says the version number of MS compilers. However, MS compilers are not supposed to support GNU extensions.

> How can I do the same `#ifdef` to check whether OS is compiling my python code using GNU and MS visual studios?

```
#if (defined(__GNU__) && defined(_MSC_VER))
   // ...
#endif
```

However, there is no chance of having both these conditions!

Comment: which library does the `defined()` module come from?

Comment: `defined` is C++ keyword and it will be used in preprocessors.

Comment: I suspect that `#if (defined(__GNU__) && defined(_MSC_VER)` is pretty much equivalent to `#if 0`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Do you mean no MS compiler has GNU macros? Yes, I just tied to answer the question. `_MSC_VER` and `__GNU__` together! I agree with you.

Comment: @MM. I would hope no Microsoft compiler defined `__GNU__` (and no version of g++ defines `_MSC_VER`).  Such macros are normally used to test which compiler you're using, so that you can have compiler specific variants.  (There are better ways of handling this, but the conditional compilation on such variables is widespread.)

Comment: Is there a python equivalence to do the same checks?

Comment: @alvas no, because python is defined by a reference implementation, not a standards document

Comment: @masoud `__GNU__` is indicating the target operating system is GNU Hurd. So, what you wrote is "Are we compiling with the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler and targeting the GNU Hurd operating system ?".

Answer (score 3):

Different compilers support different features, sometimes in different ways. You're finding a series of `#ifdef` blocks to enable support according to whatever compiler is building the code; for example the GNU compiler would automatically define `__GNUC__`. `__CC_ARM`, `__ICCARM__`, `__GNUC__`, `__TASKING__` are all defined by certain compilers the project has been ported to and is interested in.

The `__attribute__((unused))` entry is a GNU-specific indicator (though other compilers may support this now too) to state that the symbol it's attached to may be unused and so the compiler should warn you about that condition.

As to how to use these ifdefs to determine what compiler is building your code -- do it in the same manner that you're reading in another project for building C. These are not factors for your python code.

Comment: `__attribute__((unused))` suggests that symbol _may_ be unused, not that it definitely is unused.