# Make compiler assume that all cases are handled in switch without default

Tags: c++, switch-statement, g++

Let's start with some code. This is an extremely simplified version of my program.

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint16_t dummyColorRecepient;

void updateColor(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    uint16_t colorData;
    switch(iteration)
    {
    case 0:
        colorData = 123;
        break;
    case 1:
        colorData = 234;
        break;
    case 2:
        colorData = 345;
        break;
    }
    dummyColorRecepient = colorData;
}

// dummy main function
int main()
{
    uint8_t iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        updateColor(iteration);
        if (++iteration == 3)
            iteration = 0;
    }
}
```

The program compiles with a warning:

```
./test.cpp: In function ‘void updateColor(uint8_t)’:
./test.cpp:20:25: warning: ‘colorData’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     dummyColorRecepient = colorData;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

As you can see, there is an absolute certainty that the variable `iteration` is always `0`, `1` or `2`. However, the compiler doesn't know that and it assumes that switch may not initialize `colorData`. (Any amount of static analysis during compilation won't help here because the real program is spread over multiple files.)

Of course I could just add a default statement, like `default: colorData = 0;` but this adds additional 24 bytes to the program. **This is a program for a microcontroller and I have very strict limits for its size.**

I would like to inform the compiler that this switch is guaranteed to cover all possible values of `iteration`.

Comment: why do you want to do that? You can silence the warning either globally or locally for that single switch statement

Comment: Can you just use `dummyColorRecepient` instead of `colorData `

Comment: Use an *enumeration* instead of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))?

Comment: throw an exception in the default switch case. If the definition is changed, then all functions using it should be changed too.

Comment: @drescherjm @Someprogrammerdude As I wrote, this is just very simplified example. In the real program there is a lot of other operations, the numbers are generated in more complicated way and `dummyColorRecepient` is a function that sends the data.

Comment: @user463035818 I want to make sure that compiler will not consider this an undefined behavior.

Comment: @Neijwiert How do exceptions even work on microcontroller? Wouldn't this generate a lot of additional code?

Comment: there is no way compiler will consider this as undefined behavior. Its just a warning, meaning, it potentially is a bug, but it isnt in this case

Comment: I woud expect the exception to be more code than the `default: colorData = 0;`

Comment: This particular program, assuming nothing else is linked into it, indeed does not have undefined behaviour. It's the assumption that'll get you. I wonder whether giving the function internal linkage might help... _(edit: nah, doesn't)_

Comment: Enum wont work because this variable is used in a different way if in some cases. (I've made sure it is reset to 0 before I start using this function.)

Comment: @NO_NAME an enum will work. Define an enum for all possible values, then simply have the calling function cast its data value to the enum type when passing it to this function, then have a `case` for each enum value. The compiler will see all values are processed. The alternative is to use `iteration` as a key into a lookup table or `std::map` to get the `colorData` valie, or use `iteration` in a fixed calculation, and get rid of the `switch` altogether.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> As you can see, there is an absolute certainty that the variable iteration is always 0, 1 or 2.

From the perspective of the toolchain, this is not true. You can call this function from someplace else, even from another translation unit. The only place that your constraint is enforced is in `main`, and even there it's done in a such a way that *might* be difficult for the compiler to reason about.

For our purposes, though, let's take as read that you're not going to link any other translation units, and that we want to tell the toolchain about that. Well, fortunately, we can!

If you don't mind being unportable, then there's [GCC's `__builtin_unreachable` built-in](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) to inform it that the `default` case is not expected to be reached, and should be considered unreachable. My GCC is smart enough to know that this means `colorData` is never going to be left uninitialised unless all bets are off anyway.

```
#include <stdint.h>

volatile uint16_t dummyColorRecepient;

void updateColor(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    uint16_t colorData;
    switch(iteration)
    {
    case 0:
        colorData = 123;
        break;
    case 1:
        colorData = 234;
        break;
    case 2:
        colorData = 345;
        break;

    // Comment out this default case to get the warnings back!
    default:
        __builtin_unreachable();
    }
    dummyColorRecepient = colorData;
}

// dummy main function
int main()
{
    uint8_t iteration = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        updateColor(iteration);
        if (++iteration == 3)
            iteration = 0;
    }
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac9cc4c016debbb9))

This won't add an actual `default` branch, because there's no "code" inside it. In fact, when I plugged this into Godbolt using x86_64 GCC with `-O2`, the program was *smaller* with this addition than without it — logically, you've just added a *major* optimisation hint.

There's actually [a proposal to make this a standard attribute in C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0627r0.pdf) so it could be an even more attractive solution in the future.

Comment: If having a different value than specified is unexpected behavior, why not throw an exception in the default case instead (assuming exceptions are enabled)?

Comment: @Neijwiert: that's what assertions are for. Exceptions can be handled.

Comment: @Neijwiert If the OP can't accept the overhead of another assignment statement, I doubt they can accept the overhead of stack unwinding and exception handling!

Comment: Well, off course my functions won't work if I use them incorrectly. This is small self-contained driver-like program. I know exactly how this function is called and what condition will be fulfilled.

Comment: My mistake, missed that part.

Comment: @NO_NAME The language doesn't know that ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know. This is the premise of my question :) I need to know how to tell it.

Comment: @NO_NAME There try that

Comment: `__builtin_unreachable` works great. The program is even smaller than before! Probably the check for value `2` was optimized out. I wish that kind of things would be a part of the standard but in this case there is no other compilers for this platform anyway.

Comment: @NO_NAME [They're working on it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0627r0.pdf) :)

Answer (score 6):

Use the "immediately invoked lambda expression" idiom and an `assert`:

```
void updateColor(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    const auto colorData = [&]() -> uint16_t
    {
        switch(iteration)
        {
            case 0: return 123;
            case 1: return 234;
        }

        assert(iteration == 2);
        return 345;
    }();

    dummyColorRecepient = colorData;
}
```

- The lambda expression allows you to mark `colorData` as `const`. `const` variables must always be initialized.
- The combination of `assert` + `return` statements allows you to avoid warnings and handle all possible cases.
- `assert` doesn't get compiled in release mode, preventing overhead.

---

You can also factor out the function:

```
uint16_t getColorData(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    switch(iteration)
    {
        case 0: return 123;
        case 1: return 234;
    }

    assert(iteration == 2);
    return 345;
}

void updateColor(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    const uint16_t colorData = getColorData(iteration);
    dummyColorRecepient = colorData;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this generate maybe return without return value warning? Or is lambda special case?

Comment: Why does this help?

Comment: @appleapple In terms of code size it should be smaller (maybe) - it certainly won't be larger, and the assertion will trap bugs in debug mode, better than the original program would.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it does not make much difference with a default case to `case 2:` and `assert(iteration<2)`

Comment: @appleapple: they have completely different meaning. Also the assertion is not compiled outside of debug mode.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I don't see the difference, can you explain more?

Comment: What about `default: assert(false)`?

Comment: @Artyer Will still warn in release. In fact even with the assert most likely.

Comment: This reminds me of a question from late last year and I think there _was_ a way to have an assert that the compiler "understood" for a goal just like this. But no idea where it got to

Comment: I think there is some sort of compiler-specific `assume` statement.

Comment: @appleapple: `default` is an extra branch. `assert` is a debug-only "sanity check". It's like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `__builtin_unreachable` for g++ (Not sure about other compilers)

Comment: @Artyer This is g++. (avr-g++ to be specific) `__builtin_unreachable` seems good. Could you write an answer?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo well I mean something like `{assert(...); switch{case 0: {...} case 1: {...} default: /*case2:*/...}}`

Comment: @Artyer Oi oi, that's the badger!

Comment: The general idea of replacing the last `case` with `default` is good, although it decrease the readability. I might use that if I won't find any other way that leaves my intent clear.

Comment: @NO_NAME You can also make the last case fall through to `default` (or vice versa), with a suitable comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this to compile without warnings simply by adding a `default` label to one of the cases:

```
switch(iteration)
{
case 0:
    colorData = 123;
    break;
case 1:
    colorData = 234;
    break;
case 2: default:
    colorData = 345;
    break;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
uint16_t colorData = 345;
switch(iteration)
{
case 0:
    colorData = 123;
    break;
case 1:
    colorData = 234;
    break;
}
```

Try both, and use the shorter of the two.

Comment: They both work and seem to generate the same assembly code. I still like the accepted answer more, though. The result is the same and it telegraphs my intent clearer.

Comment: @NO_NAME: I have to agree with you! I just tried out the accepted answer on GCC for ASM86, and it is shorter than my suggestions.

Comment: Huh, this is such a simple and easy solution (just to get rid of the warnings) though in hindsight - good one!

Answer (score 1):

I know there have been some good solutions, but alternatively `If` your values are going to be known at compile time, instead of a switch statement you can use `constexpr` with a `static function template` and a couple of `enumerators`; it would look something like this within a single class:

```
#include <iostream>

class ColorInfo {
public:
    enum ColorRecipient {
        CR_0 = 0,
        CR_1,
        CR_2
    };

    enum ColorType {
        CT_0 = 123,
        CT_1 = 234,
        CT_2 = 345
    };

    template<const uint8_t Iter>
    static constexpr uint16_t updateColor() {

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_0) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_0 << '\n';
            return CT_0;
        }

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_1) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_1 << '\n';
            return CT_1;
        }

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_2) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_2 << '\n';
            return CT_2;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    const uint16_t colorRecipient0 = ColorInfo::updateColor<ColorInfo::CR_0>();
    const uint16_t colorRecipient1 = ColorInfo::updateColor<ColorInfo::CR_1>();
    const uint16_t colorRecipient2 = ColorInfo::updateColor<ColorInfo::CR_2>();

    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Recipient0: " << colorRecipient0 << '\n'
              << "Recipient1: " << colorRecipient1 << '\n'
              << "Recipient2: " << colorRecipient2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The `cout` statements within the `if constexpr` are only added for testing purposes, but this should illustrate another possible way to do this without having to use a switch statement provided your values will be known at compile time. If these values are generated at runtime I'm not completely sure if there is a way to use `constexpr` to achieve this type of code structure, but if there is I'd appreciate it if someone else with a little more experience could elaborate on how this could be done with `constexpr` using `runtime` values. However, this code is very readable as there are no `magic numbers` and the code is quite expressive.

---

-**Update**-

After reading more about `constexpr` it has come to my attention that they can be used to generate `compile time constants`. I also learned that they can not generate `runtime constants` but they can be used within a `runtime function`. We can take the above class structure and use it within a runtime function as such by adding this `static function` to the class:

```
static uint16_t colorUpdater(const uint8_t input) {
    // Don't forget to offset input due to std::cin with ASCII value.
    if ( (input - '0') == CR_0)
        return updateColor<CR_0>();
    if ( (input - '0') == CR_1)
        return updateColor<CR_1>();
    if ( (input - '0') == CR_2)
        return updateColor<CR_2>();

    return updateColor<CR_2>(); // Return the default type
}
```

However I want to change the naming conventions of the two functions. The first function I will name `colorUpdater()` and this new function that I just shown above I will name it `updateColor()` as it seems more intuitive this way. So the updated class will now look like this:

```
class ColorInfo {
public:
    enum ColorRecipient {
        CR_0 = 0,
        CR_1,
        CR_2
    };

    enum ColorType {
        CT_0 = 123,
        CT_1 = 234,
        CT_2 = 345
    };

    static uint16_t updateColor(uint8_t input) {
        if ( (input - '0') == CR_0 ) {
            return colorUpdater<CR_0>();
        }
        if ( (input - '0') == CR_1 ) {
            return colorUpdater<CR_1>();
        }
        if ( (input - '0') == CR_2 ) {
            return colorUpdater<CR_2>();
        }

        return colorUpdater<CR_0>(); // Return the default type
    }

    template<const uint8_t Iter>
    static constexpr uint16_t colorUpdater() {

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_0) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_0 << '\n';
            return CT_0;
        }

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_1) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_1 << '\n';
            return CT_1;
        }

        if constexpr (Iter == CR_2) {
            std::cout << "ColorData updated to: " << CT_2 << '\n';
            return CT_2;
        }
    }
};
```

If you want to use this with compile time constants only you can use it just as before but with the function's updated name.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto output0 = ColorInfo::colorUpdater<ColorInfo::CR_0>();
    auto output1 = ColorInfo::colorUpdater<ColorInfo::CR_1>();
    auto output2 = ColorInfo::colorUpdater<ColorInfo::CR_2>();

    std::cout << "\n--------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Recipient0: " << output0 << '\n'
              << "Recipient1: " << output1 << '\n'
              << "Recipient2: " << output2 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

And if you want to use this mechanism with `runtime` values you can simply do the following:

```
int main() {
    uint8_t input;
    std::cout << "Please enter input value [0,2]\n";
    std::cin >> input;

    auto output = ColorInfo::updateColor(input);

    std::cout << "Output: " << output << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And this will work with runtime values.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the original program - come up with a variant on this solution that can loop through the three implementations and we'll talk ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can add this too a while loop; I was just illustrating the point of using `constexpr`.

Comment: Actually fair point you can just put all three in a while loop haha never mind

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Depending on whether the OP's input data is runtime or compile time would determine if this code structure would work or not. I'm not sure if there is a way to use runtime values with `constexpr`.

Comment: I don't know why everyone is complaining about magic numbers as if it was real code and not some dumbed down example. The real assignment looks similar to this: `colorData = makeColorData(colors[0][0], Color::BLACK, Color::BLACK);`.

Comment: It is a nice try but the values in my code are totally non constexpr. Actually, I call function `updateColor` from other file through a function pointer (there are reasons to do that). Have upvote anyway for an original solution.

Comment: @NO_NAME I have updated my answer to show how it can be used in a runtime context.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are sure you won't have to handle other possible values, you can just use arithmetic. Gets rid of he branching and the load.

```
void updateColor(const uint8_t iteration)
{
    dummyColorRecepient = 123 + 111 * iteration;
}
```

Comment: Well, this could work if I use constant values in the real code, not only in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to extend the [Lightness Races in Orbit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148888/3052438).

The code I'm using currently is:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
__builtin_unreachable();
#else
__assume(false);
#endif
```

`__builtin_unreachable()` works in GCC and Clang but not MSVC. I used [`__GNUC__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19908922/3052438) to check whether it is one of the first two (or another compatible compiler) and used [`__assume(false)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60802864/3052438) for MSVC instead.

### Update for C++23

C++23 has introduced a function [`std::unreachable()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/unreachable) (in the header `<utility>`) which does this in a portable way.